# Is there a way to rotate the object and then calculate its x and y coordinates as if it was turned around some point without measurement accuracy?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to rotate the object with the property rotation, and then calculate its x and y coordinates as if it was turned around some point 
without measurement accuracy?

```
public static function pointRotate (object:DisplayObject, center:Point,angle:Number) : void
{
var r:Number = angle * Math.PI / 180;
var s:Number = Math.sin(r);
var c:Number = Math.cos(r);
var dX:Number = object.x - center.x;
var dY:Number = object.y - center.y;

object.rotation += angle;
object.x = center.x + dX * c - dY * s;
object.y = center.y + dX * s + dY * c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package  
{
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

public function pointRotate(object:DisplayObject, center:Point, angle:Number) : void
{
    // return to zero
    angle += object.rotation;
    var a0:Number = - object.rotation * Math.PI / 180;
    var s0:Number = Math.sin(a0);
    var c0:Number = Math.cos(a0);
    var dX0:Number = object.x - center.x;
    var dY0:Number = object.y - center.y;

    object.rotation = 0;
    object.x = Math.round(center.x + dX0 * c0 - dY0 * s0);
    object.y = Math.round(center.y + dX0 * s0 + dY0 * c0);

    // new rotation
    var r:Number = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    var s:Number = Math.sin(r);
    var c:Number = Math.cos(r);
    var dX:Number = object.x - center.x;
    var dY:Number = object.y - center.y;

    object.rotation += angle;
    object.x = center.x + dX * c - dY * s;
    object.y = center.y + dX * s + dY * c;
}

}
```